# Styling a Backlog item based on a Tag

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I would like to be able to highlight a row on a backlog in much the same way as you can with styling rules on a board view of the backlog.  I want to be able to add a tag called "QA Ready" and then any row that matches the criteria to be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

There is no styles for backlogs. You may post your idea to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) or use [excel integration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mapo/2018/10/26/vsts-azure-devops-add-in-for-excel-for-users-without-visual-studio-installed/) with built-in styles for cells. Or create a custom report.